# Magento Advance Search Exact Result For Particular Attribute Value

Tags: advanced-search

I have a magento store where i have used magento advance search on home page. Works fine. In search form there is an attribute (`caliber`) which is actually a text type attribute but i m showing this attribute as dropdown in fronted (Used custom query to fetch the attribute value of all the product). It's  also working fine. I want to show the exact result with this attribute value. Example : if `caliber` value is `9mm` then only this product should show but it rather shows other products whose attribute value is `7mmX39mm`  since this has 9mm as well.
I have changed search type mode from LIKE to FULLTEXT but both of mode are giving same result for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified `prepareCondition` function in `advanced.php` page

```
app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Advanced.php
```

Replaced below code

```
if (strlen($value) > 0) {
if (in_array($attribute->getBackendType(), array('varchar', 'text', 'static'))) {
$condition = array('like' => '%' . $value . '%'); // text search
} else {
$condition = $value;
}
}
```

BY

```
if (strlen($value) > 0) {
$condition = $value;
}
```

I got desire output.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100%, but I'm reasonably sure Magento doesn't have that functionality out of the box.  If you wanted it, you'd need to make your attribute a non-text element.

If you're comfortable with custom programming in Magento, the approach I'd take (assuming a modern Magento version) is

1. Setup an event observer for the `catalog_product_collection_load_before`
2. Return early in the event observer method if the full action name isn't `catalogsearch_advanced_result` (i.e. you're not on the search results page) or there's not a value for `caliber` in the request
3. Add an explicit `=` filter to the collection for the value of `caliber`

Re: #3, the code looks something like this

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('caliber', $value);
```

Where `$value` is populated from the request post.

Comment: thank you for your effort. I have fixed the issue in another way.

Comment: @monojitbanik It's good form to add your solution if you asked the question and solved it yourself.